# Is it possible to open a new window while closing the current one?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I want to open a new window while closing the current one.

```
class UserInterface:          
def __init__(self, master, username):      
    self.master = master
    self.master.title('Kill Smoking')
    self.master.geometry("500x500")
    labelInterfaceTitle = Label(self.master, text = "Welcome to Kill Smoking")
    labelInterfaceTitle.grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)
    Planbtn = Button(self.master, text = "Access Smoking plan", command = self.AccessPlan)
    Help_pagesbtn = Button(self.master, text = "Support pages")
   
    self.progress_username = username
    

    Planbtn.grid(row = 10, column = 10)
    Help_pagesbtn.grid(row = 12, column = 10)
```

Here is my function to open a new window, however what would I need to do to close the current one?

```
def AccessPlan(self):
    pass_progress_username = self.progress_username
    self.AccessPlan = Toplevel(self.master)
    self.app = SmokingPlan(self.AccessPlan, pass_progress_username)
```

Comment: Is one window a root `Tk` window and the other a `Toplevel` or are they both `Toplevel`? You can of course close existing windows or even just withdraw them.

Comment: yup the starting one is a root Tk

Comment: However if i close the existing root Tk window all my windows end up closing

Answer (score 0):

You can use withdraw() like the following example.

```
import tkinter as tk


def new_window():
    new_root = tk.Toplevel()
    new_root.geometry("500x500")
    root.withdraw()

    
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
button = tk.Button(root, text="new window", command=lambda: new_window())
button.pack()


    
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: do you how i could make the window re appear so it shows where i last left off?

Comment: You should be able to call root.deiconify() to bring the window back.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend *not* destroying the root window. Tkinter is designed to always have a root window. Instead, delete the contents of the root window and reuse it.

```
def AccessPlan(self):
    ...
    for child in self.master.winfo_children():
        child.destroy()
    self.app = SmokingPlan(self.master, pass_progress_username)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to open a new window while closing the current one.

Yes, you can close your current one by adding `root.withdraw()`

Code:

```
def AccessPlan(self):
    root.withdraw()
    pass_progress_username = self.progress_username
    self.AccessPlan = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
```